# getJSON - unable to target buttons using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Hi guys I am currently having an issue but have no clue what's going wrong.

```
        $.each(data.result, function(){
        $("tbody").append("<tr id='order_"+this['order_id']+"'><td>"+this['type']+"</td><td></td><td>"+this['description']+" </td><td>"+this['amount']+"</td><td>Edit | <a href='#' id='"+this['order_id']+"' title='Delete' class='delete'>X</a></td></tr>");
```

this code is appended to the page and I am trying to implement a delete function to it by parsing the order_id. However, I am unable to select the 'delete' class that's appended in this method.

Ive tried putting a delete button with the delete class and it works.. But when they are dynamically created by getJSON, it just doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Any advice would be appreciated Thanks!

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function(){
        alert('hey');
        var element = $(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
        {
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "delete.php",
           data: info,
           success: function(){
         }
        });
         }
        return false;
        });
        });
        </script>
```

And here is the page's source - my_script is the file that holds the update function to fetch data from the database

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/my_script.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() {
$(".delete").click(function(){
alert('hey');
var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var info = 'id=' + del_id;
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
{
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){
 }
});
 }
return false;
});
});
</script>






</head>

<body onload="updates();">
<table width="100%" id="sortme" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #CCC ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><strong>Line Type</strong></td>
    <td width="50" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><strong>S/N</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><strong>Description</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><strong>Amount</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#EFEFEF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>



<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could it have to do with the order in which the body is written and the jquery click handler is attached to the delete button. If that happens in the wrong order it does not work.

Comment: right now, i call the respective jquery libraries, and run the above script..

following the script is the body and table where the code is written to dynamically

Comment: have added the page's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating your event handler for delete when there is no delete DOM element.  You need to use the .on method and use a delegate that references your target (the class delete) -

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){ ::all of your delete code:: };
```

I don't like the idea of attaching this to the body but it'll work for this example.  I'd try and attach this to the lowest element possible which is going to be the parent to the dynamic content.

Comment: body is not defined, you would need to wrap that -> "body"

Comment: Thanks! yes it was missing the quotes, - i went on to use the "tbody" selector for now.

Comment: @user3448267 - if that was the answer, would you mind marking it correct?  Thanks.

Comment: @xCNPx - Thanks for the heads up.  I was spacing on my jQuery.  I updated my answer.

Comment: There is one more error. It's also missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the function. });

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your binding to : since you are dynamically creating the elements, nothing is actually bound to them. This will bind to existing and new elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
```

Comment: thanks! i understand better now, is there any implications if we use a 'global' selector like document vs a more specific one like body or tbody? i m guessing not at least for this case, but in more complex situations where there are more than one delete classes that would actually matter?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new DOM element you have to reload the jquery function to make it work, what you can do is add `$(".delete").click` inside a function, for example...

```
function reloadClick(){
  $(".delete").click(func...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Then, after you finish the loop `$.each(data.result`, execute the function `reloadClick()`

```
$.each(data.result, function(){
  ...
  ...
}
reloadClick();
```